# How to make my customized keras layer converge correctly? Gradient issue?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Background:
I am trying to use an HW classification engine that performs as follows:

1. Input is 12x12 image
2. On each 4x4 block (there are 3x3 blocks) it is applying a transform of the format Out4x4=Weight4x4 x In4x4 x Weight4x4' (a matrix representation of 4x4 transform) - by default, it is using a dct4x4 but this kernel is programable
3. As a result, there are 3 x 3 x 16 "dct coefficients", each 3x3 are weighted averaged to generate 16 "dct coefficients"
4. A complex classification process is deciding which of the 2 classes this image belongs to.

What I tried:

I wanted to find the "best" transform instead of using the default DCT.
I tried creating a CNN using Keras and Tensorflow that will simulate the feature extraction process. I tried reading examples and looking at the Keras code of DepthwiseConv2D, for example, and created the following customized Keras layer :

```
class ChildDenseTensor(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units, activation=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.units = units
    self.activation = activation
  def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "units": self.units,
            "activation": self.activation,
        })
        return config    
  def build(self, input_shape):
    input_dim = input_shape[-1]
    self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(1, 4,4, self.units), initializer='random_normal')
  def call(self, inputs):
    input_dim = inputs.shape[0]
    if input_dim is not None:
        input_dim=input_dim
    else:
        input_dim =1
    out = tf.zeros((input_dim,12,12))
    tmp_img_ts = tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor(()), (0, 0, 0))
    for img in range(0, input_dim): #quite a lot of work here to get the correct formating
        for i in [0,4,8]:
            for j in [0,4,8]:
                y = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(self.W[0],(4,4)), tf.reshape(inputs[img,i:(i+4),j:(j+4)],(4,4))), tf.reshape(self.W,(4,4)), transpose_b=True)
                if j==0:
                    dim0 = tf.reshape(y,[1,16])
                else:
                    dim0=tf.concat([dim0, tf.reshape(y,[1,16])],0)
            if i==0:
                dim1=tf.reshape(dim0,[1,3,16])
            else:
                dim1 = tf.concat([dim1, tf.reshape(dim0,[1,3,16])],0)
        if img==0:
            dim2= tf.reshape(dim1,[1,3,3,16])
        else:
            dim2 = tf.concat([dim2, tf.reshape(dim1,[1,3,3,16])],0)
    return dim2
```

and built the following model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Input((12,12,1)), 
        ChildDenseTensor(units=1, activation=tf.nn.relu), #, input_shape=(12,12,1) output_shape=(3,3,16)
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D( pool_size=(3,3)),# -> (1,1,16) #averaging the "coefficients", I also tried 3x3 conv averages
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(hparams[HP_FILTER_NUM], 1, activation='relu'),# classification layers - I also tried more layers and various number of filters but with no substential improvement
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
       ])
```

I tried also more complex models but in all of them, the model training is very slow and does not converge to reasonable results.

**My questions**:

1. Am I required to produce the gradients somehow? I did not see that this was done in the examples or the Keras code but if I should do it then how and if I don't need then is it calculating it by some approximation?
2. Is there an easier solution to my problem? Is there something incorrect in my implementation?

Comment: Hi Rehal :) I think you would benefit to be more concise in what you are asking. Without diving deep, I would answer your first question like this: No, you don't need to build a gradient. As long as your graph can be built (using only tf operations in your call function) the backend will take care of that. However, be careful with if statements in there. You want your gradient to be smooth and not show any singularities, which can happen if you chop up your function with ifs (can lead to no convergence of your optimizer).

Comment: For your second question, maybe a more direct problem statement or runnable code example could help you get an answer.

Comment: Hi Nyquist, thanks for the first answer! 
I don't think that if statements are causing issues, I replaced that code with an implementation that is based on tf.estimator and no ifs and the behavior is identical.
Thanks also for your remark regarding my second question. I guess that it is not closed formed enough so I'll try to break the "surprising" behaviors into smaller questions. 
I guess that "what would be a good solution to my problem" would not get an answer, as you pointed out to me.